# Randomly choosing a tuple set and then removing itself from the orignal tuple list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I've been trying `.remove()` and `del` but for some reason I am unable to delete a tuple...

```
listpack_list = (["data", "data", "data"], ["test", "test", "test"], ["sof", "sof", "sof"])
```

I ideally want to randomly choose a tuple list for example: `["test", "test", "test"]`

The first variable which is `listpack_list[1][0]` would be printed and the other two elements would be put into the variables Main1 and Main2 it would then proceed to remove itself from the listpack_data.

Everytime it randomly chooses a tuple set it would do the printing and changing the variables removing.

Any pointers as to how I can achieve this?

Comment: tuples are immutable - you can't delete items from them...

Comment: What do you mean by "tuple list"? I don't think that term means what you think it does.

Comment: The outside thing is a tuple, and the inner ones (in [] brackets) are lists. You can't delete from a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You cannot delete an item from a tuple as it is immutable.
2. So, pick the item to be deleted and copy the necessary values to variables
3. And then using comprehension rebuild the tuple without that particular element.

   ```
   listpack_list = (["data", "data", "data"], ["test", "test", "test"], ["sof", "sof", "sof"])
   import random
   rem = random.randrange(3)
   varToBePrinted, Main1, Main2 = listpack_list[rem]
   listpack_list = tuple(item for index, item in enumerate(listpack_list) if index != rem)
   print varToBePrinted
   ```

Answer (score 2):

First, as others have said tuples are immutable. You can't change a tuple in place but you can create a new tuple by subscripting or comprehending over the tuple.

If you're talking about doing things to the list inside the tuple, be careful because things in Python get weird here. You could clear the whole thing out with pop:

```
In [11]: listpack_list = (["data", "data", "data"], ["test", "test", "test"], ["sof", "sof", "sof"])

In [12]: listpack_list[0].pop()
Out[12]: 'data'

In [13]: listpack_list
Out[13]: (['data', 'data'], ['test', 'test', 'test'], ['sof', 'sof', 'sof'])
```

While other operations seem to fail but still work (!):

```
In [13]: listpack_list
Out[13]: (['data', 'data'], ['test', 'test', 'test'], ['sof', 'sof', 'sof'])

In [14]: listpack_list[1] += ['test']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-68991a0001f4> in <module>()
----> 1 listpack_list[1] += ['test']

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

In [15]: listpack_list
Out[15]: (['data', 'data'], ['test', 'test', 'test', 'test'], ['sof', 'sof', 'sof'])
```

So, because the immutable tuple contains mutable lists, you can alter things inside the tuple, but this is definitely not the best approach. If you have control of the implementation just make a list of lists instead of a tuple at the initial step. If you don't, I'd recommend just using a comprehension to get a list then work with that.